# set theory notation $\in \uparrow$ in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm reading the following set of notes

http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~yorgey/settheory/index.html

and on page 6 of the full set of notes (or first page of the second link), the symbol $\in \uparrow$ is used, though $\uparrow$ isn't quite right because its more like half that....

Anyway, I don't know what it is.  I think it's roughly something like the analogy of $\le$ is to $<$ as $\in$ is to $\in \uparrow$ but I'm not sure.

Any help appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 5):

The symbol in question is $\upharpoonright$, which is used for the **restriction** of a function or a relation to a subset of its domain. In particular:

- If $f : A \to B$ is a function and $U \subseteq A$, then $f \upharpoonright U : U \to B$ is the function defined by $(f \upharpoonright U)(a)=f(a)$ for all $a \in U$;
- If $R$ is a relation on a set $X$ and $U \subseteq X$, then $R \upharpoonright U$ is the relation on $U$ defined for all $x,y \in U$ by $x\, (R \upharpoonright U)\, y$ if and only if $x\,R\,y$.

In this case, ${\in} \upharpoonright x$ is the restriction of the set membership relation to $x$. So what it means to say that $\langle x, {\in} \upharpoonright x \rangle$ is a well-ordering is that $x$ is totally ordered by $\in$ and every inhabited subset of $x$ has a minimal element with respect to the relation $\in$.

---

P.S. the $\LaTeX$ code for $\upharpoonright$ is `\upharpoonright` (or `\restriction` — thanks Misha).

Comment: P.P.S. The other $\LaTeX$ code for $\restriction$ is `\restriction`.

Comment: @Mariano: ??? I did look at the notes (else I wouldn't know what the OP was talking about) and I still believe that ${\in} \upharpoonright x$ is the restriction of the $\in$ relation to the set $x$. This is in Definition 4.2.

Comment: @Misha, and P.P.P.S., it's actually $\rm\LaTeX$ (`\rm\LaTeX`) in the MathJax context... :)

Comment: thank you for the informative answer and for also broadening my LaTeX lexicon.

Comment: So does the fact that we consider the restriction to $x$ affect what the minimal elements are (with respect to $\in$)?

Comment: @Clclstdnt: Not at all. For most purposes, you can just pretend that the $\upharpoonright x$ part is dropped altogether. The reason some people choose to write ${\in} \upharpoonright x$ is because $\in$ is a class-relation, whereas ${\in} \upharpoonright x$ is a set-relation, i.e. a subset of $x \times x$.